# Using SiriKit in MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, sirikit

Can I use SiriKit for MacOS, not iOS?
Because I see in the documentation page that it supports MacOS but there is nothing at all about usiage of Siri in MacOS, only iOS.
Sorry if this is a repeat question, but I didn't see it anywhere.

I'm working on a Mac program that will take voice commands, and NSSpeechRecognizer isn't quite doing it for me.

I want something a little more dynamic so I can set alarms, make dates, give more natural commands, etc.

Every open source speech engine I've found is tailored toward iOS.
Maybe you can direct me with this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think steps would be same for both iOS and MacOS to implement SIRI kit

Comment: @aBilal17 not quite. There is even no SiriKit framework. `No such module 'SiriKit'`

Comment: Just add IntentExtension from iOS part and use it.

Comment: @aBilal17 can you please tell me how to do that? Maybe few tips, like what to search and for what to look?

Comment: ok,, just create a project for MacOS and after that follow the steps to integrate siri kit as this url. https://www.raywenderlich.com/155732/sirikit-tutorial-ios

Comment: @aBilal17 no, I can create it but the problem is that it's incompatible with MacOS project. There is not `SiriKit` in `Capabilities`. I mean how to combine iOS Extension with MacOS?

Comment: Yeah you are right.

Comment: Hi @J.Doe did you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

SiriKit is an umbrella term that covers the **Intents** & **IntentsUI** framework. See official documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit).

To clarify, there is no actual `SiriKit.framework`, it's just `Intents.framework` and `IntentsUI.framework` being collectively referred to as **SiriKit**.